# Remove the wrapper `div` from the whole `h1 - h6` tag and only wrap the current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove the wrapper `<div class="headWrap">` from the whole `h1 - h6` tag and I need only wrap the current heading tag when I click on this.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/q8yhoxhd/4/

**HTML:**

```
<h1>
    Heading Test content 1
</h1>
<h2>
    Heading Test content 2
</h2>
<h3>
    Heading Test content 3
</h3>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', function(event){
        var clickedTag;
            clickedtag = event.target;
      event.stopPropagation();
      var headings = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
      if($(clickedtag == headings)){
      $(clickedtag).wrap($('<div/>').addClass('headWrap'));
      }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.headWrap {
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: It helps if you provide a working jsfiddle including the required libraries https://jsfiddle.net/udgvx7ec/

Comment: Hi, thank for your time! probably its not required any libraries

Comment: jQuery is required

Comment: Have you included the jQuery script? The JS is jQuery syntax.

Comment: Yes, i included Jquery 3.2.1

Comment: @Issac Not in your jsfiddle you didn't, hence the syntax error and nothing working. `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` Compare your jsfiddle to the one I have posted in my previous comment. The only change different is the required library **jQuery** has been included to enable the jQuery scripts to be used. Without it you cannot use jQuery. The browser console is your best friend while working with javascript or any javascript libraries.

Comment: Updated with 1.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 things.

1. Include jQuery
2. unwrap all other headers and wrap only the clicked header.

This is the same code from the fiddle. All I did is

Added jQuery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

added code to unwrap all headers on each click event.

```
$(headings).unwrap();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    var clickedTag;
   clickedtag = event.target;
      event.stopPropagation();
      var headings = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
      $(headings).unwrap();
      if($(clickedtag).is(headings)){
      $(clickedtag).wrap($('<div/>').addClass('headWrap'));
      }
  });
  });
```

```css
.headWrap {
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Heading Test content 1
</h1>
<h2>
Heading Test content 2
</h2>
<h3>
Heading Test content 3
</h3>
<p>Test</p>
```

*<sup>Thanks to gaetanoM. I missed that point. You can't simply use `==`. use jQuery</sup>* .is() *instead to check similarity.*

Comment: Ohh you are right! I just forgot the Jquery `unwrap`.. thank you soo much dear. It will work for me

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
if($(clickedtag == headings)){
```

If you need to test if current target element is an header element you can write:

```
if ($(clickedtag).is('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')){
```

> [.is(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/is/):  Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    var clickedTag;
    clickedtag = event.target;
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(clickedtag).is('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')){
        $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').unwrap();
        $(clickedtag).wrap($('<div/>').addClass('headWrap'));
    }
});
```

```css
.headWrap {
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>
    Heading Test content 1
</h1>
<h2>
    Heading Test content 2
</h2>
<h3>
    Heading Test content 3
</h3>
```

Another approach can be based on event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6', function(event){
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6', function(event){
  var clickedTag;
  clickedtag = event.target;
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').unwrap();
  $(clickedtag).wrap($('<div/>').addClass('headWrap'));
});
```

```css
.headWrap {
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>
    Heading Test content 1
</h1>
<h2>
    Heading Test content 2
</h2>
<h3>
    Heading Test content 3
</h3>
```

In order to remove the div for the non clicked element you can write:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'h1,h2,h3', function(event) {
      var $heading = $(this);
      //unwrap others (if they are wrapped)
      $('.headWrap').contents().unwrap();

      if ($heading.parent('.headWrap').length) {
        // unwrap this one if second click - (remove if not desired behavior)
        $heading.unwrap()
      } else {
          // or wrap this one
          $heading.wrap($('<div/>', { class: 'headWrap' }));
      }    
  });
});
```

```css
.headWrap {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Heading Test content 1
</h1>
<h2>
Heading Test content 2
</h2>
<h3>
Heading Test content 3
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the headWrap class from the element right before adding it to the clicked element:

```
$('.headWrap').removeClass('headWrap');
```

Also, is there an additional reason you are wrapping them in a div? There is no reason to for this effect.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udgvx7ec/2/)